# How to apply spacing between divs using inline-table

Tags: php, html, css

Please excuse the excessive use of echo here, as I'm using IP.Content which allows pure PHP or pure html, but not a mix of them both. I'm attempting to get a layout in which I have the following

```
xxx-------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Where a `-` resembles free space. I am trying to not use floating variables, so using a table display seems like the proper way to handle this. Here's my simplistic code below, you can see by the two widths what I'm going after, however the table display automatically expands to fill the remaining space.

```
echo '<div style="display: inline-table; width: 100%;">';
echo '<div id="categories" style="width: 20%; display: table-cell;">';
echo '<div class="box">';
echo 'Hello world2.';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div id="content" style="width: 70%; display: table-cell;">';
echo '<div class="box">';
echo 'Hello world.';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use borders to space the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML-Padding.

for more referece : www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp